# Dlang static templated struct/class functions

Tags: templates, d

I've ran into an error that I'm unable to solve when trying to use the templated static function `addID` below:

```d
module static_example;

struct Foo(T: long) {

   public static int addID(E)(E foo1, E foo2) {
       return foo1.get() + foo2.get();
   }

   private:
       T ID;

   alias T Type;

   public this(T ID) {
       this.ID = ID;
   }

   public T get() {
       return this.ID;
   }
}
```

The error I receive with the call `rdmd static_example.d` is:

```
Error: template Foo(T : long) does not have property 'addID'
```

I don't really understand this error. I assumed this isn't a problem with the literal tag `@property` (didn't seem to be, and I don't understand `@property` functions either way), so I made a few other structs to test all together in main:

```d
struct Bar {

    public static int addID(Bar bar1, Bar bar2) {
        return bar1.get() + bar2.get();
    }

    private:
        int ID;

    public this(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int get() {
        return this.ID;
    }

}

struct Batz(T: long){

    public int addID(E)(E foo) {
        return this.get() + foo.get();
    }

    private:
        T ID;

    alias T Type;

    public this(T ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public T get() {
        return this.ID;
    }
}

void main() {
    auto foo1 = Foo!int(27);
    auto foo2 = Foo!int(13);
    int staticTemplateAdd = Foo.addID(foo1, foo2);

    auto bar1 = Bar(27);
    auto bar2 = Bar(13);
    int staticAdd = Bar.addID(bar1, bar2);

    auto batz1 = Batz!int(27);
    auto batz2 = Batz!int(13);
    int templateAdd = batz1.addID(batz2);
}
```

These other classes are practically the same, except `Bar` uses a static `addID` and `Batz` uses a templated `addID` while foo is both static and templated.

`Foo` is the only struct that throws an error, and with that I'm stumped. I was following a D Template tutorial (https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/D-templates-tutorial/blob/master/D-templates-tutorial.md near the top if you're interested), but its example was both foreign (to me), and seemed to be slightly different than what I was trying to do. Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: How are you trying to call `addID`? Expand your question, please.

Comment: @sigod main is at the bottom of the code. Sorry, I could've made it more apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in your Foo struct

```d
public static int addID(E)(E foo1, E foo2) {
   return foo1.get() + foo2.get();
}
```

May I suggest to return auto? That way it'll fit any return type of the passed template type's get function.

Secondly how are you calling `Foo.addID`? Because it works fine for me calling it like

```d
Foo!(long).addID!(Foo!long)(a, b);
```

Where `Foo!(long)` is the static instance of `Foo` and `Foo!long` is the passed type to `addID`

And it works fine when I call it from a non-static instance too.

```d
auto foo = Foo!long(5);
foo.addID!(Foo!long)(a, b);
```

Comment: So the issue was that I was calling the static function without giving it a type for Foo. Now that I think about it, it makes sense since there's nothing to infer which type of Foo class I was calling for. I changed my static call from Foo.addID(foo1, foo2) to Foo!int.addID(foo1, foo2), and that fixed the issue. And your answer got me there, so thanks!

Comment: FYI, I don't know the etiquette on picking answers like this. Because yours helped immensely, but it doesn't explicitly have the answer. I marked it as correct, but idk if an edit should be made to include it more directly.